# Take previous Cumulated Value if blank matrix visual

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I have a matrix where Day on X-Axis, Year and Quarter on Y-axis. Cumulated amount on Values.

Matrix: [image]

wherever there is a blank, it should take the previous amount instead of displaying blank. for example, on Day 2 for 2024 Q1, it should show 787,544. On day 6,7,8 for 2023 Q4, it should show 10,201,258.
below is the dax for cumulative amount.

```
Cumulative Amount = 
  var maxnum = MAX('Sheet1'[Day])
  var tmp = FILTER(ALL(Sheet1[Day]),'Sheet1'[Day]<=maxnum)
  return CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Amount]),tmp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming in your Matrix, you are using `[Day]` column from a date table. If so, update the measure to:

```
Cumulative Amount = 
  var maxnum = MAX('YourDateTable'[Day])
  var tmp = FILTER(ALL(Sheet1[Day]),'Sheet1'[Day]<=maxnum)
  return CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Amount]),tmp)
```

---

If it is all from one table - then you will need to have separate table for the Days. Create a new Calculated Table like:

```
Matrix Days = DISTINCT(Sheet1[Day])
```

or

```
Matrix Days = SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1, 9, 1), "Day", [Value])
```

Then update your measure to:

```
Cumulative Amount = 
  var maxnum = MAX('Matrix Days'[Day]) // <-- updated
  var tmp = FILTER(ALL(Sheet1[Day]),'Sheet1'[Day]<=maxnum)
  return CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Amount]),tmp)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for response. My source is a view, All the columns are coming from a single view. Thanks!

Comment: See updated answer above, 2nd part.

Comment: Hey! that didn't actually work. Below is the sample pbix file, I am working for, sending you for reference, Many thanks in advance.
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1GpELeyAoM8b1PzhyIeTqyqwmdBj9yrFx

Comment: A couple of tweaks: remove the relationship between `dim_day` and `Sheet1`, and ensure the Day column `[Column1]` is set as a Number data type (instead of Text). Then with the measure given in the answer above, you'll get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sTBj.png)